# ckeditor jquery adaptor set template path

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

How would one set the ckeditor template file using the jquery adapter?
i.e mytemplates.js contains the templates which var does one set in a jquery adapter config?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same config entry, the jQuery adapter is just a little wrapper, everything under the hood is just the normal CKEditor.

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.templates_files

Comment: the jquery adapter doesn't use the same variable convention as the docs.
'code' var config = {
uiColor: '#ffffff',
stylesCombo_stylesSet: [],
format_tags: "p;h2;h3;h4;div",
contentsCss : '/js/admin/editorstyles/default.css',
extraPlugins : 'stylesheetparser',
scayt_autoStartup:true,
toolbar_Full: [['Templates','Styles','Format','FontSize','TextColor', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline','-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList','-','Scayt','PasteText'],
                            ['Image','Link', 'Unlink'], ['Undo', 'Redo'],['Source', 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']]
                         
  };

Comment: my guess would be in the wrapper to set
   templates_files:[                                   '/pathtomytemplates/template.js']

but this doesn't work

Comment: Again: there's no magic in the jquery adapter, it just provides some extra methods to use CKEditor better from jQuery, but the constructor jst passes the config object to the normal constructor http://dev.ckeditor.com/browser/CKEditor/trunk/_source/adapters/jquery.js#L145